# Plugin PHP Sublime text 3

Tags: php, sublime-text-2

Alguém sabe o nome do plugin para PHP que mostra uma descrição da função do php na minha IDE, quando coloco o cursor em cima dela? Por EX:

função:

```
str_replace();
```

Ao colocar o mouse sobre ela aparece uma descrição do que ela faz, e o que ela recebe:

```
str_replace($find, $string, $replace) // essa função localiza uma string e a substitui na string informada. (pode ser em ingles essa descrição)
```

Basicamente o que eu busco é isso: (uma descrição da função dentro do próprio editor)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Procure por `code intelligence`. A resposta do Wictor já contém o plugin que deseja para isso no seu editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**GotoDocumentation**

> "Abre a documentação da palavra-chave na qual o cursor está."

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GotoDocumentation

**SublimeCodeIntel**

https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel

Comment: Esse ai eu to ligado, mas tem um melhor ainda que é nesse esquema que eu coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Editei, acredito que é o segundo plugin que você quer.

Comment: adicionei uma imagem para exemplificar o que busco

Comment: Então é a SublimeCodeIntel que você precisa.

Comment: Não consegui encontrar essa funcionalidade no plugin